# Issue deploying Spring GS Rest Service to Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, rest, cloud-foundry

I imported the **"Spring Getting Started - Rest Service"** as a new project into Spring Tools. Works fine locally. After building the JAR with `mvn clean package` and editing the `manifest.yml` to correctly point to the JAR location I've tried to deploy this project to Cloud Foundry. The project deploys fine but fails shortly after starting with the following error.

> Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
>   App instance exited with guid 96f2fbd0-aaa3-48aa-9181-55abf624c626 payload: 
>   
>   `{
>   "cc_partition"=>"default", 
>   "droplet"=>"96f2fbd0-aaa3-48aa-9181-55abf624c626", 
>   "version"=>"9ee684a6-7d62-4f45-9481-97d4e87c3895", 
>   "instance"=>"db08e1b5fba44d938f4904ae4c921878", 
>   "index"=>0, 
>   "reason"=>"CRASHED", 
>   "exit_status"=>-1, 
>   "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout",
>   "crash_timestamp"=>1439875540
>   }`

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: If helpful, sometime back I had tried CF, and have detailed the steps here -> http://naturalprogrammer.com/2015/02/06/pivotal-cloud-foundry-spring-boot-web-applications/

Comment: my question is why does the "GS - Rest Service" running locally on port 8080 work fine for me but when deploying it to cloud foundry it gets killed because it fails to accept connection within health check timeout. Am I supposed to change some configuration values before pushing it to cloud foundry?

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- increase timeout by calling `cf push -t 180`
- set server port to 8080 in cloud profile
- or change `health-check-type` inside the **manifest.yml**:

  ```
  ---
  applications:
  - name: ...
    health-check-type: process
  ```